# Transformers: WordLevel tokenizer produces strange vocabulary

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

Training the WordLevel tokenizer I receive strange vocabulary. Bellow is my code:

```
data = [
    "Beautiful is better than ugly."
    "Explicit is better than implicit."
    "Simple is better than complex."
    "Complex is better than complicated."
    "Flat is better than nested."
    "Sparse is better than dense."
    "Readability counts."
]

from tokenizers.models import WordLevel
from tokenizers import Tokenizer, models, normalizers, pre_tokenizers, decoders, trainers

tokenizer = Tokenizer(models.WordLevel())

trainer = trainers.WordLevelTrainer(
    vocab_size=100000,
)

tokenizer.train_from_iterator(data, trainer=trainer)

tokenizer.get_vocab()
```

The output is the following:

```
{'Beautiful is better than ugly.Explicit is better than implicit.Simple is better than complex.Complex is better than complicated.Flat is better than nested.Sparse is better than dense.Readability counts.': 0}
```

Please explain what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Your data is defined incorrectly, the len() of your data is one.
It need commas, like so:

```
data = [
    "Beautiful is better than ugly.",
    "Explicit is better than implicit.",
    "Simple is better than complex.",
    "Complex is better than complicated.",
    "Flat is better than nested.",
    "Sparse is better than dense.",
    "Readability counts.",
]
```

Additionally, you want to pass in a sequence of sequences you can use the map() function to apply split() like so:

```
tokenizer.train_from_iterator(map(lambda x: x.split(), data), trainer=trainer)
```